# Split, group, count and display data from delimited strings

Tags: php, arrays, explode, counting, delimited

I have a list of teachers with properties like:

```
teacher 1 skills = English, Math
teacher 1 gender = Male

teacher 2 skills = Spanish, Math, Law
teacher 1 gender =  sex = Female

teacher 3 skills = English, Geography
teacher 3 gender = Male
```

First of all I want to tell how many English (and any other matter) teachers there are, since the skills can be various, what I do is to check for a duplicate in the array and count it:

```
     $stack = array();
     $blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=author' );
  foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
     $myUsers = $user->user_description (this is the skill list);
     $mystrings = strtolower($user->user_description);
     $descTokens = explode(',', $mystrings);
     $descTokens = array_map('trim',$descTokens);
     $stack = array_merge($stack, $descTokens);
  }
     $count_values = array();
     foreach ($stack as $a) {
       @$count_values[$a]++;
     }
     $total_duplicates = 0;
     foreach ($count_values as $a) {
       if($count_values[$a]<=1){
          unset($count_values[$a]);
       } else{
          $total_duplicates += $count_values[$a];
       }
      }
```

Then do this

```
    <ul class="margin-top-20">
      <?php
        foreach ($count_values as $key=>$count ) {
          echo '<li>'.$count.' di <strong>'.$key.'</li>';
        }
      ?>
    </ul>
```

That's correct, the output is right:

```
2 English teachers
2 Math teachers
1 Spanish
1 Law
1 Geography
```

But I also have the gender, so ideally I would like to have

```
2 English teachers, 1 male, 1 male
2 Math teachers, 1 male, 1 female
1 Spanish, 1 female
1 Law, 1 female
1 Geography, 1 male
```

I tried adding:

```
      $sex = array();
      $user_sex = get_user_meta( $the_user_id, $gender, $single ); 
      array_push($sex, $user_sex);
      foreach($descTokens as $lang){
        $userSex[$lang] += $user_sex;  
      }
      foreach ($count_values as $key=>$count ) {
        echo '<li>'.$count.' di <strong>'.$key.' gender '. $userSex[$key] .'</li>';
      }
```

But that's not right.

**Fullcode I am trying**:

```
  <?php
    $stack = array();
    $userID = array();
    $nPost = array();
    $listmaterie = array();
    $materie = array();
    $gender = 'sesso';
    $single = true;
    $sex = array();
    $blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=author' );
    $userSex = array();
    foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
        $myUsers = $user->user_description;
        $mystrings = strtolower($user->user_description);
        $descTokens = explode(',', $mystrings);
        $descTokens = array_map('trim',$descTokens);
        $stack = array_merge($stack, $descTokens);
        $the_user_id = $user->ID;
        $numPosts = count_user_posts( $the_user_id );
        array_push($userID, $the_user_id);
        array_push($nPost, $numPosts);
        $user_sex = get_user_meta( $the_user_id, $gender, $single ); 
        array_push($sex, $user_sex);
        foreach($descTokens as $lang){
          $userSex[$lang] += $user_sex;  
        }
     }
       // get the count for each language by counting the duplicate strings;
     $count_values = array();
     foreach ($stack as $a) {
       @$count_values[$a]++;
     }
     $total_duplicates = 0;
     foreach ($count_values as $a) {
       if($count_values[$a]<=1){
          unset($count_values[$a]);
       } else{
          $total_duplicates += $count_values[$a];
       }
      }
     $count_sex = array();
     foreach ($sex as $b) {
       @$count_sex[$b]++;
     }
     $total_duplicates_sex = 0;
     foreach ($count_sex as $b) {
       if($count_sex[$b]<=1){
          unset($count_sex[$b]);
       } else{
          $total_duplicates_sex += $count_sex[$b];
       }
      }
    ?>
    <h3 class="margin-top-40">Numero complessivo docenti su Jikū:</h3>
    <ul class="margin-top-20 margin-bottom-20">
    <?php
      $totalInsegnanti = count($userID);
      echo '<li>'. $totalInsegnanti .'</li>'; 
    ?>
    </ul>
    <h3>Totale insegnanti per materia su Jikū:</h3>
    <ul class="margin-top-20">
      <?php
        foreach ($count_values as $key=>$count ) {
          echo '<li>'.$count.' di <strong>'.$key.' gender '. $userSex[$key] .'</li>';
        }
      ?>
    </ul>
    <h3>Totale insegnanti sesso su Jikū:</h3>
    <ul class="margin-top-20">
      <?php 
        foreach ($count_sex as $key=>$count_sex) { 
            echo '<li>'.$count_sex.' <strong>'.$key.'</strong></li>'; 
        }
      ?>
    </ul>
```

**Dumps**
**I have 3 users**

```
var_dump($stack);
```

> array(11) { [0]=> string(8) "francese" [1]=> string(7) "chimica" [2]=>
>   string(6) "fisica" [3]=> string(7) "scienze" [4]=> string(7) "inglese"
>   [5]=> string(6) "fisica" [6]=> string(7) "chimica" [7]=> string(8)
>   "spagnolo" [8]=> string(8) "francese" [9]=> string(6) "fisica" [10]=>
>   string(8) "italiano" }

```
var_dump($sex);
```

> array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "maschio" [1]=> string(7) "maschio" [2]=>
>   string(7) "femmina" }

Comment: *"I have a list of teachers with properties"* - what does that actually look like in code? What data structure are you using? A custom object? Are the teachers in the  `$user` variable? Is that an object or array?

Comment: can you provide sample input array?

Comment: dont post the questions like this?tell us where you are getting error?

Comment: @domdom question updated with the var_dumps

Comment: @Bhaskar question updated with the var_dumps

Comment: @lalithkumar I found it a bit complicated to just say "I am not getting the gender" therefore I thought to explain it all and well showing the full steps and code

Comment: Somehow I don't really understand. But here is some general piece of advice: wherever your teacher/user data comes from, first turn them to objects. Write a class that can hold all the required information, `subject` (English, Math, ...), `gender` (male, female, ...) - this will make it easier to work with those. (If this is already the case, ignore me)

Comment: @domdom yeah they are attached to the single user, yet they come from different fields. The English, Math is a comma separated list that's why all the work to get them into an array and count them as duplicate (since a duplicate in this case means 2 teachers with English and so on). I need to attach the gender to the final output tho

Comment: While you had good intentions posting all that information, I think you now have a bit of an information overload in the question. At least that's true for me - I don't really get it anymore. Maybe you can simplify all of this. Check out how to create a [mcve]

Comment: (Basically, we'd need to see what your input looks like, what your current output looks like, what the output is supposed to look like and then the relevant, specific code that you use in your attempt to turn the input into the output - and all of that as reduced as possible)

Comment: hey @domdom but I did wrote what the output looks like and what is supposed to look like. Also there is the whole code right there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
foreach($blogusers as $user){
    foreach(explode(', ',$user->user_description) as $skill){  //"comma then space" delimited
        $result[$skill][]=get_user_meta($user->ID,'sesso','true');  // push user's gender into subject's array
    }
}

foreach($result as $subject=>$gender_array){
    echo "<div>",sizeof($gender_array)," $subject teachers";
    $count_genders=array_count_values($gender_array);  // avoids php NOTICE @ array_walk
    array_walk($count_genders,function($v,$k){echo ", $v $k",($v!=1?"s":"");});
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Considering your sample input data, my method will output this:

```
2 English teachers, 2 Males
2 Math teachers, 1 Male, 1 Female
1 Spanish teachers, 1 Female
1 Law teachers, 1 Female
1 Geography teachers, 1 Male
```